# Extremely Huge time take for executing my following query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I just make some queries for select data from my server. The query is:

```sql
SELECT 
    ROUND((SUM(clength)/1048576),2) AS logical_MB,
    ROUND((SUM(plength) /1048576),2) AS physical_compr_MB,
    ds_doc.archiveno,
    ds_arch.archiveid
FROM ECR.ds_comp,
    ECR.ds_doc,
    ECR.ds_arch
WHERE ds_comp.docidno=ds_doc.docidno
    AND ds_doc.archiveno =ds_arch.archiveno
GROUP BY ds_doc.archiveno,
    ds_arch.archiveid;

result what is expecting is :

   

 9708,24            9704,93         9   Vee3    0,009255342
    13140,55        12682,93        10  Vf5     0,012095385
    104533,94       89183,02        3   Mdf4    0,085051556
    72346,34        48290,63        7   Sds2    0,046053534
```

But this query almost take one day. Any idea for optimize this query please?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Any explain plan to show us?

Comment: and how i can perform this for the above query ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/query-execution-plans.html#GUID-BE44BB45-C061-4F3A-8F18-4AAC5F74C68A

Comment: Verify the execution plan for this query. Check which indexes are used, and if these are the correct indexes. A day is very long, which make me wonder how large the dataset is you're working with?

Comment: {527817908} row in my database

Comment: In addition to the execution lan, can you tell us what system this is running on (nbr of cpus, type of storage, how much ram)? which db version? and why there are 5 columns in your output while the query returns 4?

Comment: If you query 500 million records - yes it simply takes some time!

Comment: Record count and table size are very different things. 500M records of 10 numeric fields and 500M records of 100 varchar2(200) fields will give you different read performance.

Comment: For large data volumes without highly specific selection criteria, indexes are usually a source of poor performance. If the [execution plan](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/explain-plan-utility.html) or [SQL Monitor report](https://sqlmaria.com/2017/08/01/getting-the-most-out-of-oracle-sql-monitor/) shows nested loops then that is most likely your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provide close to no information that is [required](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) to help with performance problem, so only a general checklist can be provided

**Check the Query**

The query does not *qualify* the columns `clength`and `plength` so please check if they are defined in the table `ds_comp` - if not, maybe you do not need to join to this table at all...

Also I assume that `docidno` is a **primary key** of `ds_doc`  and `archiveno` is PK  of `ds_arch`.  If *not* you query will work, but you will get a different result as you expect due to duplication caused by the join (this may also cause excesive elapsed time)!

**Verify the Execution Plan**

Produce the execution plan for your query *in text form* (to be able to post it) as follows

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = '<sometag>' into   plan_table  FOR
... your query here ...

SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', '<sometag>','ALL'));
```

Remember that you are joining **complete tables** (not only few rows for some `ID`), so if you see `INDEX ACCESS` or `NESTED LOOP` there is a **problem** that explains the long runtime.

You want to see only `HASH JOIN` and `FULL TABLE SCAN` in your plan.

**Index Access**

Contrary to some *recommendations* in other answers if you want to profit from *Index definition* you **do not** need indexes on *join columns* (as explained above). What you can do is to *cover all required attributes in indexes* and perform the query using only *indexes* and ommit the table access at all. This will help if the tables are bright, i.e. the row size is large.

This definition will be needed

```
 create index ds_comp_idx1 on ds_comp (docidno,clength,plength);
 create index ds_doc_idx1 on ds_doc (docidno,archiveno); 
 create index ds_arch_idx1 on ds_arch (archiveno,archiveid);
```

and you will receive this plan

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation               | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT        |              |  1119K|    97M|   908  (11)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY          |              |  1119K|    97M|   908  (11)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN             |              |  1119K|    97M|   831   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN            |              |  1001 | 52052 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN     | DS_ARCH_IDX1 |    11 |   286 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| DS_DOC_IDX1  |  1001 | 26026 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |    INDEX FAST FULL SCAN | DS_COMP_IDX1 |  1119K|    41M|   818   (2)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("C"."DOCIDNO"="D"."DOCIDNO")
   3 - access("D"."ARCHIVENO"="A"."ARCHIVENO")
```

Note the `INDEX FULL SCAN` and `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` which means you are scanning the data from the *index* only and you *do not need to perform the full table scan*.

**Use Parallel Option**

With your rather *simple query* there is not much option to improve something. What works always is to deploy a *parallel query* using the `/*+ PARALLEL(N) */` hint.

The precontition is that your database is configured for this option and you have hardware that can deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rewrite using explicit joins:

```sql
    SELECT 
        ROUND((SUM(clength)/1048576),2) AS logical_MB,
        ROUND((SUM(plength) /1048576),2) AS physical_compr_MB,
        d.archiveno,
        a.archiveid
    FROM ECR.ds_comp c
         INNER JOIN ECR.ds_doc d ON c.docidno=d.docidno
         INNER JOIN ECR.ds_arch a ON d.archiveno=a.archiveno
    GROUP BY d.archiveno,
        a.archiveid;
```

2. Check indexes exist on join columns `c.docidno`, `d.docidno`, `d.archiveno`, `a.archiveno`